# Laravel - what is best practice about custom request?

Tags: laravel

I use 2 customs requests, one for the register, and one for the password change.

In both, there is the same password validation. How can I avoid duplicating this code and have it in only one request?
I don't know if it is possible, I would like to have your opinion.

Kylian

Comment: Possible with request type. Example : for store use `POST` request, and for update, use `PUT` or `PATCH` request. And if your update method is `PUT` then check  the unique field (expect current field `id`)

Comment: create one separate request to store validation rules

Comment: @bhucho Ok but If I want to change the rules for the password, I need to check all the custom requets which contains this rules ?

Comment: you can name your requests to contain a specific type of rule, eg password related rules in a request named `UserPasswordRequest`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own `CustomRequest` class to validate your requests in Laravel.

```
Class CustomRequest extends Request
{
  public function rules()
  {
     return [
              'password' => 'required',
              'username' => 'required'
             ];
   }

 public function messages()
  {
    return [];
  }
}
```

use this above class in controller function.

```
public function functionName(CustomRequest $customRqt)
{
  try {
       dd($customRqt->all());
  } catch (\Throwable $th) {
    $thow $th;
  }
}
```

this will help you to avoid duplicacy. I haven't run this code, but this will give you an idea.